How to differentiate between onChange and onInput when both are triggered at the same time?
For context, I am using angular and ionic to make this mobile app. But I think the problem/answer can be generalized.
Im working on a mobile app that can take a user's input with keyboard or voice (through voice access) and store its value(s) and how it got inputed. When a user input using a keyboard, it will trigger the ionInput (onInput) and the ionChange (onChange). But if the user use voice access, it will only trigger ionChange (onChange). How do I differentiate between a keyboard input vs a voice input when both are triggered? Below is an example of the HTML file:
HTML:

<ion-input (ionInput)="handleKeyboardInput($event)" (ionChange)="handleInputChange($event)"></ion-input>

I also read that onChange is triggered when the <input> loses focus. But in this case, the handleInputChange() is triggered even if the focus is still on the <input>.
All of the solution I have tried so far is prone to a race-condition. Rxjs might be able to help me, but I am still exploring that possibility. Any tips and suggestions would be appreciated.
Edit:
For additional information, I am testing this using an android device. Specifically the pixel 6. It might behave differently if I tried it on the browser. But since my use case would be running the app on a device, I am not testing it on the browser.

@NullUserException I have not tried, but both function will trigger anyway and both input will be recorded in the database, which is not how I needed it to behave. If a user uses a keyboard, it will trigger both ionInput and ionChange as they type. I need prioritize the ionInput function instead of the ionChange function. I need the ionInput data to go through the backend and not the ionChange.

I am looking at the documentation here (admittedly I've never used the ionic framework), and it doesn't look like the ion-input component supports voice recognition. How are you getting the voice input into the text area? Are you using the SpeechRecognition API? Or are you just relying on the Android/iOS keyboard's voice input functionality?

If you are just using the speech-to-text functionality that's embedded in the phone's keyboard, then I don't think it's possible to know whether they actually typed or used voice. On Android for example, the OS fires both input and change if you use the keyboard's speech-to-text.

@NullUserException So I use voice access, which is an app that you can download from the play store. When you turn it on, you can use voice commands to do things on your phone. Such as saying, "type hello world", and it will type in the whole string to the . The following is the link to the voice access documentation: https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151848?hl=en

If it isn't possible, any suggestions on an alternative way I can go about implementing voice accessibility features besides what I am using now?

Yeah, this is going to be similar to the keyboard's speech-to-text. The OS simulates typing into the text input, so it's hard for you to know where it came from.

What you can do is use the SpeechRecognition API, which would give you full control over how that works. It would even allow users who don't have voice access installed to use voice recognition. The downside is that you'd have to implement it. Don't worry, it's fairly easy - you basically have to put in a button that tells the browser when to start and stop speech-to-text

Is only ionChange gets triggered when using voice?

@YashMaheshwari Yes, ionChange gets triggered only when using voice. using voice will trigger ionChange, ionInput. And using keyboard will trigger ionInput. Something that I notice as well is that if I say, "type q" using voice access, and it just typed the letter q on the <input>, it will only trigger ionInput but not ionChange. If I say, "type Hello", it will trigger both ionChange and ionInput. So it seems the number of character mattered also.

I have tested in Ionic 5
I've noticed that both ionInput and ionChange events are triggered for text input change, whether it's through voice, manual typing, drag-and-drop, or copy-paste operations. However, I've observed that the inputType value is available only in ionInput.
Here's what I've found:

Copy paste: insertFromPaste
Voice input: insertCompositionText
Manual typing: insertText
Drag and drop: insertFromDrop

Sample code 1:
<ion-input (ionInput)="handleKeyboardInput($event)" (ionChange)="handleInputChange($event)"></ion-input>


handleKeyboardInput(event) {
  if(event.detail.inputType == "insertText") { 
    //I got inputType value only in ionInput
    //Put you manual typing logic code
  }
}


Sample code 2:
By using of id we can track the inputType
<ion-input  id="textcheck" </ion-input>
  
  handleInputChange(){ //ionViewWillEnter
    const editable = document.getElementById("textcheck");
    editable.addEventListener("input", this.logInputType);
  }

  logInputType(event) {
    console.log(event.inputType);
  }


Did you try this on a real device (android/ios) or on the browser?

I have tryed in Redmi Note 11T 5G Android and i used capacitor 5 angular 13 and ionic 5

That is interesting because I cannot access the inputType value in detail. Not sure if its because of the device I am using
